# How to process Asterisk's queue_log file

Tags: asterisk

I am setting up a contact center and need some data for management. Since we are using Asterisk queues, the place to get them is from queue_log, I believe. So, for avoiding eventual future errors, I would like to know some points about processing this file.

- What do you use to do? Parse the file and insert the data on a relational database? Or parse it everytime you need a report?
- Do you use some type of log rotating on it, to avoid it to become too big?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to use a mode called Realtime, which stores the data right in a database

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. With some [Asterisk book](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/I_section12_tt1465.html), some [help with dependencies](http://www.adambotbyl.com/debian-asterisk-module-build-dependencies/) and [this amazing post](http://work.mikeboylan.com/asterisk-queuelog-to-mysql) I got it working.